# .exe - с помощью какой программы можно прочитать электронную книгу?

Tags: nexenta

Здравствуйте.

Электронная книга в виде исполняемый файл DOS/Windows .exe - с помощью какой программы можно прочитать?

Comment: простите, что советую плохое, но двойной щелчок мыши ничего не даёт?

Answer (score 1):

ехе это запускной файл, скорее всего данный екзешник является вирусом или программой для виндовс.

Comment: Запускной? Вот он, великий и могучий, бедный и несчастный русский язык....exe - это **исполняемый** (или **исполнимый**) файл. [Проконсультируйтесь][1].@Влад14, это и к Вам относится.  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.EXE

Answer (score 1):

По теме... Допускаю, что ехе-шник является (самораспаковывающимся) архивом. Допускаю также, что в нем действительно лежит "книга". Могу допустить, что книга в каком-то нестандартном формате, и в архиве с ней сразу идет и ридер (читалка)...

Скорее всего, там, помимо книги, лежит куча ненужного хлама (в лучшем случае) или вредонос (в худшем).

На мой взгляд, запускать нечто *исполняемое*, когда не хотел получить ***именно исполняемое*** - признак плохого тона и непрофессионализма... Оптимально - попробовать вскрыть архиватором (7zip etc), посмотреть, что внутри, и вытащить только нужное и полезное.

ИМХО

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить через [wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: эта прога при установке требует удалить кодеки Линукса - но не уверен, что они не пригодятся.

Answer (score 0):

ехе это запускной файл, скорее всего данный екзешник является вирусом или программой для виндовс.

Под Виндой смог просмотреть - это точно книга в этом формате.

Comment: Простите, но> это точно книга в этом форматево-первых - тавтология, а во-вторых - "в этом" это в каком???

Comment: книги в формате .EXE  - другие расширения не отображаются при чтении книги под Виндой. Странички перелистываются на экране, как будто читаю бумажную книгу. Под Убунтой не читается и не распаковывается как архив.

Comment: Попробуйте в "Свойствах папки" на вкладке "Вид" снять галочку "Скрывать расширения для зарегистрированных типов файлов". Увидите расширения и у других фалов...**Еще раз**, ".ехе" - это _приложение_ (программа, исполняемый файл). [Читать про .ехе](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exe)."Книга" - это всего лишь файл определенного формата. Но никак не программа. [Читать что такое "электронная книга"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_(%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)).

Answer (score 0):

просмотреть архиватором проще всего.Еще это может быть уже упакованная смотрелка с книгой, наподобие тех, которые раньше делались на жава для телефонов приложение на одну книгку внутри него